# Migrating NIC names in Debian 9

Tags: debian, systemd, udev

Before upgrading a server from Debian 9 to 10 I am trying to migrate, as recommended, the interface names from old naming (`eth0`, `eth1`) to new, that would be `enp1s0`, `enp2s0`. All the guides I found tell me to:

- discover old and new names (done);
- remove or comment the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, that supposedly is the only thing that keeps the old names in effect in Debian 9;
- edit `/etc` files substituting the new name to the old one and reboot crossing my fingers.

Problem is the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` is not there. Nil. So the server *should already use* the new names. In Debian 9 udev should by itself apply them.

Somewhere I saw a suggestion to check if there is a kernel command line parameter in the form `net.ifnames=0`. But there isn't.

I don't understand. Anyone can shed some light on udev NIC naming process? What udev rule should I check?

Answer (score 0):

delving into udev mysteries I found the following command that allows to debug network name assignment:
(see https://manpages.debian.org/testing/udev/systemd.link.5.en.html)

`sudo SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug udevadm test-builtin net_setup_link /sys/class/net/eth0`

```
calling: test-builtin
...
Load module index
Found container virtualization none
timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
timestamp of '/lib/systemd/network' changed
Skipping overridden file: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link.
Parsed configuration file /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link
Created link configuration context.
ID_NET_DRIVER=e1000e
Config file /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link applies to device eth1
ID_NET_LINK_FILE=/etc/systemd/network/99-default.link
Unload module index
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

where `/etc/systemd/network/99-default.link` contains only comments, so that the policy supplied in `/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link` is skipped allowing the kernel supplied names to remain in effect. Deleting the file in /etc reinstates the new naming.